# Folder/contents of class library appearing in website project of web application

Tags: asp.net

When I make an asp.net web application and add class libraries to the solution, the website project itself has a folder with the same name/contents as the class library.

Eg I make a web application called Test, add a project which is a class library, to the solution, called testAbc, and then there is a folder at the root of the website project called testAbc with the contents of the class lib.

I read why this happens in a book a while ago but can't quite remember now. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.Net is only allowed to access to code and resources in two places: the GAC and it's own application virtual directory.  If your testAbc project is not in the GAC, you must keep a copy with the application or asp.net won't be able to find it later.

I'm of the personal opinion that the ASP.Net team would do well to allow you to define an additional location to look for code in the web.config for use by small teams that want their own code library to re-use across projects and don't want to worry about strong names, but that's currently not an option.